# React Router 6 catch any URL that ends with /debug

Tags: url, parameters, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router 6.

I have an app with multiple routes

```
<Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={<Main />}
      >
        <Route
          path="dashboard"
          element={<div>dashboard</div>}
        />
        <Route
          path="account"
          element={<div>account</div>}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route
        path="login"
        element={<Login />}
      />
// ... more routes
</Routes>
```

Is there a way to display some react component for any URL that **ends** with /debug

Solutions I can think of:

- use search params, but the url would look end with `?debug=true`, I'd prefer a simple `/debug`.
- nest a `debug` route in every route in my `Routes` component hierarchy, but that's tedious (I have many routes)

Is there a smarter way?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there really that much of a difference between an URL ending with `".../debug"` and `"...?debug=true"`? The queryString parameter is probably the path of least resistence.

Comment: I get your poinr @DrewReese, this is a solid fallback, but I think that unfortunately, for a non technical audience, the search params syntax is about as exotic as Chinese :)

Comment: Well, it seems you are well aware of the alternative to serialize it into the URL path. Is the non-technical audience doing some debugging? I say let the muggles sweat it with the exotic queryString params.

Answer (score 1):

for check the url based on ending of it you can use something like this :

```js
path=":anyPage*/?debug=true
```